# Reusing functions of a prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

i'm reading the book 'Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja' (http://jsninja.com/) and wonder why a certain code block from one of the examples is coded like it is.

The example (http://jsfiddle.net/3s5bopqe/3/) builds a custom array type (MyArray) and reuses a number of functions from the Array.prototype without actually inheriting from the 'Array' type.

In the example from the book a function with a certain name is reused in the prototype of the custom type using this code

```
    MyArray.prototype[ name ] = function() {
      return Array.prototype[ name ].apply(this, arguments);
    };
```

I  believe i understand what happens here. But it seems unnecessary to me to actually use a function literal and explicitly 'apply' a function from the Array.prototype. The following code works just as well in the test setting :

```
 MyArray.prototype[ name ] = Array.prototype[ name ];
```

My question is whether there are any advantages of using the code from the book over the last code block ?

Comment: Preference. A lot of JS code, particularly in JQuery, works in the format the book lists. And consistency is always good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using

```
 MyArray.prototype[ name ] = Array.prototype[ name ];
```

you are actually copying method from Array into your object (MyArray).
In future, if Array method changes, your MyArray method wont be updated.

By using

```
MyArray.prototype[ name ] = function() {
      return Array.prototype[ name ].apply(this, arguments);
    };
```

you referred to Array method. Changes made in Array object methods are reflected in your MyArray methods. Why? Because you never copied that method, you just borrowed it (referred to its current implementation).

Answer (score 1):

There's one major difference I can see. If any of the targeted methods on `Array.prototype` gets altered after you copied them (e.g. applying a polyfill that fixes behavior) the changes will not be reflected using `MyArray.prototype[ name ] = Array.prototype[ name ];` while it would using the jsninja approach.

Depending on your point of view, you may find one or the other behavior more fitting.